# How to use unix login user names in Emacs lisp/config?

Tags: linux, postgresql, emacs, elisp

I was wondering if it is possible to use the current login user name in Emacs config files (in elisp)?

For example, some times the username and default database for a PostgreSQL database are the same as the current login Unix/Linux user name in many multi-user environment. When configuring a Emacs SQL mode and supplying user and database to connect to, something as the following can be used in the Emacs config.

```
(setq sql-postgres-login-params
      '((user :default "postgres")
        (database :default "postgres")
        (server :default "localhost")
        (port :default 5432)))
```

How can I replace the `username` and `database` from `"postgres"` to the value of `$(whoami)` in Linux/Unix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be [user-login-name](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/User-Identification.html). Just in case you don't know, be sure to no write it inside a quoted list. You can use a [backquote](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html):

```
`((user :default ,user-login-name))
```